# Need help making a script that notifies me when my battery is low

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a script that shows me the battery percentage in dwmblocks, in which I have also added the functionality to notify me when by battery percentage is low.
but the way I've written it, it keeps sending a new notification until the charge goes above 20.
how would I go about fixing that so that I only get the notification once?

Note that the script is called every 5 seconds.

```
if [ "$bat" -lt 20 ]; then
    echo "$redbg$tfg $ramp20 $bbg$bat%"
    if [ "$status" -e "Discharging" ]; then
        notify-send --urgency=critical "battery low" 
    fi
elif [ "$bat" -lt "40" ]; then
    echo "$ybg$tfg $ramp40 $bbg$bat%"
elif [ "$bat" -lt "60" ]; then
    echo "$ybg$tfg $ramp60 $bbg$bat%"
elif [ "$bat" -lt "70" ]; then
    echo "$ybg$tfg $ramp70 $bbg$bat%"
elif [ "$bat" -lt "90" ]; then
    echo "$gbg$tfg $ramp90 $bbg$bat%"
elif [ "$bat" -le "100" ]; then
    echo "$gbg$tfg $ramp100 $bbg$bat%"
    if [ "$status" -e "Charging" ]; then
        notify-send "battery sufficiently charged" 
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Is the script called each time, or just once, with the code you just wrote running inside a loop?

Comment: it's called every 5 seconds by dwmblocks.

Comment: There are many, many ways to solve that. Basically you need to save the state between runs, in a file for example. Check this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904980/variable-in-bash-script-that-keeps-it-value-from-the-last-time-running